# Alternative to FogBugz?

Tags: project-management, fogbugz, bug-tracker

FogBugz is great bug tracking and project management software. But it is not free and non-open source. Is there a good enough, open-source and free application, which can be used as replacement to FogBugz?

Actually, I like EBS (Evidence-based Scheduling) feature in FogBugz. Are there good trackers with this feature?

Comment: if you purchase the licensed version of FogBugz, it comes with the source.  Also, it is free for students and startups.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is Bugzilla, which is an open source issue tracking system.

Here is a more extensive list

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems

Answer (score 1):

While there are plenty of decent open source bug trackers such as Bugzilla (as Navi mentioned) and [Mantis Bug Tracker](http://www.mantisbt.org/), I haven't found many which also include solid project management features like FogBugz and other licensed software.

I suppose that it also depends on what kind of project you are tracking.  If it's something which doesn't require much more security than a username/password, you might find a good number of web services which can host your needs; however, if you work for a company/industry which requires more discretion (say- government?), then you most likely won't be able to take advantage of the greater web community for these needs.